# Azure Functions (python) adal authentication timeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am trying out Azure Functions with Python (linux app service plan). I have written a basic code that will authenticate my function with Azure. It uses Service principal details (set in AppSettings) via ADAL authentication. I have deployed the function via Visual Studio Code. When I run the function it runs forever, and gives me a '503' error.

As you can see the code is pretty simple, it just does an authentication. I want to know why it is running for 5 minutes and how to fix it. Am I missing anything that is causing this issue.

Code:

```
import logging
import os, adal
import azure.functions as func
from azure.mgmt.resource import SubscriptionClient
from msrestazure.azure_active_directory import AdalAuthentication
from msrestazure.azure_cloud import AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    # Retrieve the IDs and secret to use with ServicePrincipalCredentials 
    logging.info('Logging environment Variables...')
    client_id = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_ID"]
    client_secret = os.environ["AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
    client_subscription_id = os.environ["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"]
    client_tenant_id = os.environ["AZURE_TENANT_ID"]
    
    LOGIN_ENDPOINT = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory
    logging.info(f'login endoint: {LOGIN_ENDPOINT}')
    
    RESOURCE = AZURE_PUBLIC_CLOUD.endpoints.active_directory_resource_id
    logging.info(f'resource: {RESOURCE}')
    
    context = adal.AuthenticationContext(LOGIN_ENDPOINT + '/' + client_tenant_id)
    
    credential = AdalAuthentication(context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials, RESOURCE, client_id, client_secret)
    subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credential)
    
    subscription = next(subscription_client.subscriptions.list())
    logging.info(f'Client ID: {client_id}, Client Subscription ID: {subscription}')
    
    #return func.HttpResponse(f'Client ID: {client_id}, Client Subscription ID: {subscription}')
    return func.HttpResponse(f'Client ID: {client_id}')
```

Error:

```
Timeout value of 00:30:00 exceeded by function 'Functions.StorageAccountDeployer' (Id: '2ecd0e1e-ef17-44fc-a1d7-d0134b9f9e3e'). Initiating cancellation.
```

Comment: ADAL is an old library. Not sure when / if the Python version is working fine. Seems to me the timeout happened when trying to acquire the token otherwise it would give you an error right away. Review the settings and if you've granted the permission for the app to query Azure AD.

Comment: Thank you, I will check the permissions

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio looks like the Service Principal did not have permission on the subscription. You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: awesome, always happy to help. I've added as an answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on Azure AD if you've granted the permissions for the Service Principal to retrieve the token.